# Error:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Tengo el siguiente codigo en el cual quiero poder extraer el valor del metodo `size()` para saber cuantos items hay en un recycler view pero solo logro extraer el valor cuando el text view lo tengo dentro del mismo recyclerview.

Pero si lo intento extraer fuer del recyclerview me arroja el error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)`.

No he logrado saber a que se debe tengo declarado los 2 textview igual todo bien lo unico diferente es que uno esta dentro del `recyclerview` y el otro no.

Anexo imagen de cuando logro extraer el valor en el recycler view por obvias razones se va repitiendo segun los items que existan en el recycler.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El text view en el que quiero extraer el valor del metodo `size()` es el que tiene el texto de `count` que en mi layout es el `txsize` con id `countImg`.

`FotoAdapter.java`

```
public class FotoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FotoAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<Bitmap> lista;
    private Context context;

    public FotoAdapter(List<Bitmap> lista, Context context) {
        this.lista = lista;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_foto,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Bitmap bit=lista.get(position);
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(bit);
        holder.txcou.setText(lista.size() + "/13");

        if (Objects.equals(lista.size(),13)){
            holder.add.setEnabled(true);
        }else{
            holder.add.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private ImageView image;

        Button add;

        TextView txcou,txsize;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.foto);
            txcou=itemView.findViewById(R.id.size);
            txsize=itemView.findViewById(R.id.countImg);
            add=itemView.findViewById(R.id.add);
        }
    }
}
```

`fragment_gallery.xml`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lista_fotos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/style_borde_edittext"
        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fotografiar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck,MissingClass" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtrailer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Caja"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtipo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Tipo Embarque"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="count"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Agregar"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lista_fotos" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Al mismo tiempo intente usar el valor extraido para usarlo con un `IF` and `ELSE`

```
if (Objects.equals(lista.size(),13)){
            holder.add.setEnabled(true);
        }else{
            holder.add.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Item_foto.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/foto"
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="227dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/size"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Count" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Pero no logro hacer que funcione el boton continua apareciendo como habilitado no se si hice algo mal

Answer (score 0):

En tu layout `item_foto.xml` únicamente tienes el `TextView` con id `size`:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/size"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Count" />
```

Pero debes agregar el `TextView` con ID `countImg`, ya que no existe en el layout.

```
 txcou=itemView.findViewById(R.id.size);
 txsize=itemView.findViewById(R.id.countImg); //*Falta esta vista en tu layout.
```

Comment: Si pero yo quiero extraer el valor fuera del `item_foto` por que si lo declaro dentro del `item_foto` me pasara lo mismo que con el `size` se repetira muchas veces y es lo que no quiero

Comment: Ya lo hice como dijiste y sucedio lo que te comentaba me da el valor dentro del recyclerview y yo lo quiero afuera

Comment: Las vistas que deseas se van a reciclar deben de ir dentro de item_foto.xml y deben de ir dentro del layout que se carga dentro de onCreateViewHolder() , si las quieres fuera debes sacarlas pero no podrás obtener su referencia.

Comment: Okey y como logro hacer que solo se vea una vez dentro del recycler view en ves de que se este recyclando

Comment: Sacalo del  layout item_foto.xml, pero elimina la referencia a txsize=itemView.findViewById(R.id.countImg); y txsize

Comment: Lo quite del item_foto.xml  y solo deje `holder.txcou.setText(lista.size() + "/13");` en el metodo `onBindViewHolder` pero aun asi me continua dando el error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Si en tu item_foto.xml existe  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/size" y obtienes su referencia de esta forma: txcou=itemView.findViewById(R.id.size); no debería de marcar error, revisa especificamente en que linea se muestra el error.

Comment: Es que lo quite del item_foto.xml y lo puse en el fragment_gallery.xml. Por que si lo dejo en el item_foto.xml me lo repite como ya te dije y solo quiero que se muestre una ves no que se duplique y si lo mando a llamar fuera del recycler me muestra el error en la siguiente linea `holder.txcou.setText(lista.size() + "/13");`

Comment: Ya que `txcou=itemView.findViewById(R.id.size);` `R.id.size` lo tengo en el gallery_fragment.xml y asi lo saque de item_foto.xml y cuando lo llamo afuera del recycler es cuando muestra el error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference` en la linea de codigo `holder.txcou.setText(lista.size() + "/13");`